# How to populate multiple tags into input form in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have a form which has a place where a user can insert multiple tags separated by a comma into the database. I got it to insert, but I'm having trouble retrieving it to show on my edit form.

This is my Edit Action:

```
public IActionResult Edit(int id)
{
      var gallery = _ctx.GalleryImages.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);

      if (gallery == null)
          return NotFound();

      var categories = _ctx.Categories.ToList();

      var model = new GalleryFormViewModel(gallery)
      {
          Tags = gallery.Tags,
          Category = categories, 
      };

      return View("Views/Image/UploadForm.cshtml", model);
}
```

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class GalleryFormViewModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ImageTag> Tags { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Category> Category { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public IFormFile ImageUplaod { get; set; }

    public GalleryFormViewModel()
    {
        Id = 0;
    }

    public GalleryFormViewModel(GalleryImage galleryImage)
    {
        Id = galleryImage.Id;
        Title = galleryImage.Title;
        Tags = galleryImage.Tags;
        CategoryId = galleryImage.CategoryId;
    }
}
```

And here is the Form input: (I'm using this form for creating and editing the gallery)

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Tags)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Tags, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Tags)
</div>
```

Here is the Tag Model:

```
namespace SimpleImageGallery.Data.Models
{
    public class ImageTag
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the Gallery Model:

```
public class GalleryImage
{
  public virtual IEnumerable<ImageTag> Tags { get; set; }
  // ....
}
```

This is how the tags table looks in the database:

[image: My tags table]

It seems like I'm not getting any errors, maybe something is wrong in the actual input field?

Comment: `Tags` is a complex property. You cannot bind a collection of complex objects to a input (you need an input for each property of each item in the collection). Its difficult to understand what you trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 2):

There are some mistakes :

First, you have to `Include` the Tags to retrieve them from DB (if using Entity Framework):

```
var gallery = _ctx.GalleryImages.Include(m=>m.Tags).SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
```

Secondly, you are doing the same this twice :

```
var model = new GalleryFormViewModel(gallery)
      {
          Tags = gallery.Tags,
          Category = categories, 
      };
```

and

```
public GalleryFormViewModel(GalleryImage galleryImage)
    {
        Id = galleryImage.Id;
        Title = galleryImage.Title;
        Tags = galleryImage.Tags;
        CategoryId = galleryImage.CategoryId;
    }
```

Thirdly, you cannot do this : `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Tags, new { @class = "form-control" })` for a enumerable, you have to reconstruct the string.

Comment: I included the Include statement, and removed the tags from the controller and left it in the view model. I dont understand what you mean for the last part when you say I have to reconstruct the string? Im also getting: ** System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[SimpleImageGallery.Data.Models.ImageTag] ** in my input field which has to do with what you said about the string probably

Comment: When you save tags to DB, user sends you a string, you parse it to Tags, and you saved them to the DB. To edit them, you have to do the opposite, retrieve them from the DB, merge them into a string ("tag1, tag2, tag3") and send it to the page via your viewmodel (you need a new prop in your view model). On save, you will do the same as on the creation page, parse the string to Tags and save them